# Is there a way to use UTF-8 with app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, character-encoding

I'm looking for some explanation on how the app engine deals with character encodings. I'm working on a client-server application where the server is on app engine.

This is a new application built from scratch, so we're using UTF-8 everywhere. The client sends some strings to the server through POST, x-www-form-urlencoded. I receive them and echo them back. When the client gets it back, it's ISO-8859-1! I also see this behavior when POSTing to the blobstore, with the parameters sent as UTF-8, multipart/form-data encoded.

For the record, I'm seeing this in Wireshark. So I'm 100% sure I send UTF-8 and receive ISO-8859-1. Also, I'm not seeing mojibake: the ISO-8859-1 encoded strings are perfectly fine. This is also not an issue of misinterpreting the Content-Type. It's not the client. Something along the way is correctly recognizing I'm sending UTF-8 parameters, but is converting them to ISO-8859-1 for some reason.

I'm led to believe ISO-8859-1 is the default character encoding for the GAE servlets. My question is, is there a way to tell GAE not to convert to ISO-8859-1 and instead use UTF-8 everywhere?

Let's say the servlet does something like this:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("application/json");
    String name = req.getParameter("name");
    String json = "{\"name\":\"" + name + "\"}";
    resp.getOutputStream().print(json);
}
```

I tried setting the character encoding of the response and request to "UTF-8", but that didn't change anything.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I don't know about GAE, but your API looks like J2EE Servlets. There ISO-8859-1 is indeed the default. Use `resp.setCharacterEncoding()` to change the encoding or print binaries directly.

Comment: GAE uses that same API. I tried setting the character encoding in the response already, it doesn't work. :( Thanks, though.

Comment: I haven't used appengine at all, but with all appservers I had to implement a filter to force the encoding to be UTF-8 (because of the 'issue' Zeiss mentioned...stupid servlet spec). You can copy paste the filter from [tomcat](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.21/org/apache/catalina/filters/SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java) if you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Did you read this? http://macgyverdev.blogspot.com.ar/2011/09/how-to-get-character-encoding-correct.html

Comment: @Augusto: No, I didn't try that. The links I've seen use Spring, I'm not using Spring. Your link isn't loading here. I found that code elsewhere, I'll give it a shot and get back to you, thanks.

Comment: @leonbloy: Yes, it uses Spring. I'm not using Spring.

Comment: @Augusto just FTR, see the answer from leonboy. It doesn't work in GAE, apparently. :-(

Comment: Hints for debugging: what does `resp.getCharacterEncoding()` returns ? (just before the `resp.getOutputStream()` ). Do you set the character encoding after calling setContentType and before getOutputStream()? What happens if instead getOutputStream() you use getWriter() ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a way to work around it. This is how I did it:

- Used "application/json; charset=UTF-8" as the content-type. Alternatively, set the response charset to "UTF-8" (either will work fine, no need to do both).
- Base64-encoded the input strings that aren't ASCII-safe and come as UTF-8. Otherwise they get converted to ISO-8859-1 when they get to the servlet, apparently.
- Used resp.getWriter() instead of resp.getOutputStream() to print the JSON response.

After **all** those conditions were met, I was finally able to output UTF-8 back to the client.

Answer (score 17):

I see two things you should do.

1) **set system-properties (if you are using it) to utf8 in your appengine-web.xml**

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
    <property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
</system-properties>
```

*OK that above is what I have but the docs suggest this below:*

```
<env-variables>
    <env-var name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
</env-variables>
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig

2)  **specify the encoding when you set the content type or it will revert to the default**

> The content type may include the type of character encoding used, for
>   example, text/html; charset=ISO-8859-4.

I'd try

```
resp.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

You could also try a writer which lets you set the content type to it directly.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType(java.lang.String)

For what it's worth, I need utf8 for Japanese content and I have no trouble.  I'm not using a filter or setContentType anyway.  I am using gwt and #1 above and it works.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either. :-( I disabled the filter, set the system-properties as you suggested (using env-variables doesn't work, the dev server refuses to run). I then used content-type "application/json; charset=utf-8" (which I believe is correct), and it didn't work. I also copied and pasted your content-type line (which I believe is incorrect), same thing.

Comment: "resp.setContentType" was the thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to GAE, but in case you find it useful: I made my own filter:

In web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>charsetencoding</filter-name>
    <filter-class>mypackage.CharsetEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
    ...
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>charsetencoding</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

(place the filter-mapping fragment quite at the beginning of the filter-mappings, and check your url-pattern.

And

```
public class CharsetEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    }

    public void destroy() { }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }
}
```

Comment: Nope. :-( I also tried using Augusto's link and configuring the charset in web.xml as the link you posted mentioned, but it still didn't do the trick. I'm guessing GAE doesn't respect those filters somehow? I still get ISO-8859-1 back from the echo servlet.

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml GAE does support filters. However, all the filter does is set the request and response character encoding. I tried that already in individual servlets with no luck, so I guess that is what isn't working in GAE.

Comment: I also couldn't get it to work even in the development server. I think it uses Jetty to serve the requests.

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround (safe)

Nothing of these answers worked for me, so I wrote this class to **encode UTF-Strings to ASCII-Strings** (replacing all chars which are not in the ASCII-table with their table-number, preceded and followed by a mark), using `AsciiEncoder.encode(yourString)`

The String can then be **decoded back to UTF** with `AsciiEncoder.decode(yourAsciiEncodedString)`.

```
package <your_package>;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Micha F. aka Peracutor.
 * 04.06.2017
 */

public class AsciiEncoder {

    public static final char MARK = '%'; //use whatever ASCII-char you like (should be occurring not often in regular text)

    public static String encode(String s) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(s.length() + 4 * 10); //buffer for 10 special characters (4 additional chars for every special char that gets replaced)
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if ((int) c > 127 || c == MARK) {
                result.append(MARK).append((int) c).append(MARK);
            } else {
                result.append(c);
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static String decode(String s) {
        int lastMark = -1;
        ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            //noinspection InfiniteLoopStatement
            while (true) {
                String charString = s.substring(lastMark = s.indexOf(MARK, lastMark + 1) + 1, lastMark = s.indexOf(MARK, lastMark));
                char c = (char) Integer.parseInt(charString);
                chars.add(c);
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException | NumberFormatException ignored) {}

        for (char c : chars) {
            s = s.replace("" + MARK + ((int) c) + MARK, String.valueOf(c));
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.