# Java Character Encoding on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, character-encoding

I am running a GWT application on Google App Engine which passes text input from the GUI via GWT-RPC/Servlet to an API. But umlauts like ä,ö,ü are misinterpreted by the API and the API shows only a ? instead of an umlaut.

I am pretty sure that the problem is the default character encoding on the Google App Engine, which is US-ASCII: US-ASCII does not know any umlaut.

Using umlauts with the API from JUnit-Tests on my local machine works. The default character encoding there is UTF-8.

The problem does not come from GWT or the Encoding with any HTML file; I used a Constant Java String within the appliation containing some umlauts and passed it to the API: the problem appears if the application is deployed in the Google App Engine.

Is there any way to change the Character Encoding in the Google App Engine? Or does anyone know another solution to my problem?

Storing umlauts from the GUI in the GAE Datastore and bringing them back to the GUI works funnily enough.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "API shows only a ?" - where? You should ideally trace the exact data at every stage to work out *exactly* where the problem is. See http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/01/20/diagnosing-issues-with-reversible-data-transformations/

Comment: Sounds like you need to control the character encoding of your output. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907764/is-there-a-way-to-use-utf-8-with-app-engine for more details.

Comment: @DanielTung I tried to set both `<system-properties><property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8" /><property name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" /></system-properties> ` and `<env-variables><env-var name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" /></env-variables>` but it did not work.

Comment: @JonSkeet In short: Running `API.call("test äöü")` will cause the API (it sends SMS) to send "test äöü" from my machine and "test ???" from GAE.

Comment: @AndréJanus: That doesn't really help us work out where the problem is. What API is it? Do you have documentation?

Comment: @JonSkeet It is the Esendex Java SMS SDK: http://developers.esendex.com/SDKs/Java-SDK But the API works fine on my local machine (and on Tomcat 7 on a remote machine), so I am quite sure that it is the GAE.

Comment: Does it work fine locally from the App Engine "local server" (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver)? If so, you should be able to capture the network traffic, which would be helpful. If it's failing with a hard-coded string (and I'd personally express that with `\uxxxx` escape sequences to isolate the Java compiler from the mix) then it sounds like you can ignore the GWT part, and focus *just* on the API call. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: @JonSkeet The local GAE server is a very good idea, thank you! I just tried and it works fine locally. I am pretty sure that the problem is the default character encoding on the "remote" Google App Engine, which is US-ASCII.

Comment: That sounds odd... Really the API should handle the string to binary conversion... It shouldn't be using the platform default encoding. This is definitely odd... What happens if you change the platform default on your local machine to ASCII? Can you reproduce the problem then?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I can reproduce the problem by setting my local JVM Encoding to US-ASCII (-Dfile.encoding=US-ASCII).

Comment: @AndréJanus: Excellent. In that case, I'd personally regard it as a bug in Esendex, and would suggest reporting it as such - it may well be easy to fix. I'm afraid I don't know how to change the encoding on GAE, although I'm frankly surprised that it's ASCII instead of UTF-8...

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't think it's a bug in Esendex. I have the same problem and still couldn't solve it. See my question here, maybe that provides some additional information to the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204936/google-appengine-how-to-set-default-charset-file-encoding-to-utf-8-for-goo

Comment: @Micha: That just shows a similar bug elsewhere, IMO. Libraries simply shouldn't use the system default encoding, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet if so, it would be a bug of AppEngine - or how could I avoid this: If I add a API-Method to my Java-Cloud-Endpoint, say `public void testEncoding(@Named("someString") String someString)` and use Googles APIs-Explorer to test it, then the String (sent to an android-client as notification) is displayed correctly if testing locally where default encoding is UTF-8 but is displayed with ?s when deployed to AppEngine where encoding is US-ASCII

Comment: @MichaF: If that's the case I'd certainly say that's a problem, yes. But it sounds like Esendex may have the same issue of using the default encoding. Basically, lots of things may be at fault here :(

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem: the default charset of a web application deployed to Google App Engine was set to `US-ASCII`, but I needed it to be `UTF-8`.

After a bit of head scratching, I found that adding:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="appengine.file.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
</system-properties>
```

to `appengine-web.xml` correctly sets the charset to `UTF-8`. More details can be found on [Google Issue Tracker - Setting of default encoding](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35885982).

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround (safe)

I wrote this class to **encode UTF-Strings to ASCII-Strings** (replacing all chars which are not in the ASCII-table with their table-number, preceded and followed by a mark), using `AsciiEncoder.encode(yourUtfString)`

The String can then be **decoded back to UTF** with `AsciiEncoder.decode(yourAsciiEncodedUtfString)` where UTF is supported.

```
package <your_package>;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Micha F. aka Peracutor.
 * 04.06.2017
 */

public class AsciiEncoder {

    public static final char MARK = '%'; //use whatever ASCII-char you like (should be occurring not often in regular text)

    public static String encode(String s) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(s.length() + 4 * 10); //buffer for 10 special characters (4 additional chars for every special char that gets replaced)
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if ((int) c > 127 || c == MARK) {
                result.append(MARK).append((int) c).append(MARK);
            } else {
                result.append(c);
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static String decode(String s) {
        int lastMark = -1;
        ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            //noinspection InfiniteLoopStatement
            while (true) {
                String charString = s.substring(lastMark = s.indexOf(MARK, lastMark + 1) + 1, lastMark = s.indexOf(MARK, lastMark));
                char c = (char) Integer.parseInt(charString);
                chars.add(c);
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException | NumberFormatException ignored) {}

        for (char c : chars) {
            s = s.replace("" + MARK + ((int) c) + MARK, String.valueOf(c));
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you (like myself) are using the Java [flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java) on Google AppEngine, the default encoding can "simply" be fixed by setting the `file.encoding` system property through your `app.yaml` (via an [environment variable](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/openjdk-runtime#entry-point-features) that is automatically picked up by the runtime) like this:

```
env_variables:
  JAVA_USER_OPTS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```