# Google AppEngine - How to set default Charset / file-encoding (to UTF-8) for Google AppEngine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, encoding, character-encoding

**Situation**

I'm using [AppEngine Cloud Endpoints (Java)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) as backendserver for my Android-application. In a Cron-Job the server regularly downloads new data (String), filters out relevant information and sends it via Firebase Cloud Messaging to different topics (by posting HTTP-Request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send).

**The (damn simple) Problem**

The downloaded text is in German, containing letters like ä,ö,ü,ß and (to not have the famous ?s istead of these characters) ***I want to change the encoding to UTF-8***.

US-ASCII encoding is the default when deployed to AppEngine (why isn't it UTF-8 by default...). When tested locally, the default encoding of my computer is used which is UTF-8 and ***everything is working just fine***.

So all I want is `Charset.getDefaultCharset()` to return `UTF-8`.
How do I achieve this?
Thanks in advance, all help appreciated.

**What I've tried**

- adding this to appengine-web.xml:

  `<env-variables>
      <env-var name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
   </env-variables>`

  When testing locally I got IncorrectEnvironmentVariableException. When deployed encoding was still ASCII.
- adding this to `<system-properties>`-tag in appengine-web.xml:

  `<property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
   <property name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />`

  changed nothing, not only when deployed but also when I tried to use this to set the encoding to US-ASCII on local developement server, still UTF-8 was returned by `Charset.getDefaultCharset()`
- even tried to use reflection:

  `System.setProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8");
   Field charset = Charset.class.getDeclaredField("defaultCharset");
   charset.setAccessible(true);
   charset.set(null,null);`

  (caused IllegalAccessException)
- tried setting encoding as content-type-property with the HTTP-post (didn't work):

  `connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", application/json; charset=UTF-8);`

Comment: I never set any system variables, and I have no problems with any languages (German, Russian, etc.) on App Engine for the past 7 years :)

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Well, then you are lucky, I didn't change anything and the default charset was ASCII. That apparently wasn't the case for you (I envy you...) but there have been several questions on SO about changing encoding and not only I had this problem. I tried all answers of these questions, even those with lowest rating, but nothing worked. Whats wrong with AppEngine that this seems impossible to do where it should be as easy as setting one preference...

Comment: It has nothing to do with luck - or with App Engine. You should not depend on system charset - not on App Engine, not anywhere else. Look for answers on how to set UTF-8 encoding for HTTP requests.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin First of all: look at the last point of what I've tried. Second: The problem occurs way before posting the HTTP-Request. I use `Reader r = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8");` for downloading. Now when for "Ä" `r.read()` returns 196, which isn't in the ASCII-table, the casting to `char` creates a '?'. At this point everything would just be fine **if default charset of AppEngine was UTF-8**. And if I should not depend on system charset, how can I circumvent this? I cannot assign a "Ä" to a String without creating a "?".

Comment: Where do you see this "?" ? If you see it in the logs somewhere, the problem may be with the encoding in the logs, not with your code which reads the string correctly.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I see it on my Android app when receiving the message (sent with Firebase Cloud Messaging Message) which has the string of the downloaded chars in the payload and displays it in a notification. As I already mentioned, everything works fine when running on local developement server and the notification is displayed correctly. Only when deployed to AppEngine, I get the "?"s in the notification. I traced this error back to the casting of `r.read()`.

Comment: Why do you cast char at all? Try `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));` and then `reader.readLine()`

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I appreciate the time you afford to try to help me :) But BufferedReader calls `read(char[],int,int)` on the InputStreamReader which calls `StreamDecoder.read(char[],int,int)`, which does exactly what I do: cast the chars to int (see here line 172: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.java#StreamDecoder.read%28char%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29). This is just consequential, because somehow the downloaded bytes have to be decoded and cast to char - if I do it or BufferedReader does it for me makes no difference.

Comment: I use exactly this code in App Engine for many years in several totally different apps, and I have no problems with encoding. UTF-8 comes in, UTF-8 comes out. For example, the information on this page has been pulled from MusicBrainz and Wikipedia, then stored in Cloud Datastore: https://rebelation-com.appspot.com/#Artist:5509649262444544

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I could also use your code and have no problems - if default charset was UTF-8. Do you know what `Charset.getDefaultCharset()` returns for you? Maybe the default charset actually is UTF-8 so you never had to bother. As already mentioned in my question, I wondered why default charset is ASCII. It would make more sense to have UTF-8 as default, as it covers many more chars (i. e. languages) while not requiring more bytes to store. Anyway, that you didn't have any problem with encoding on AppEngine doesn't mean mine is inexistent but I appreciate your effort to try to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

If you have problems with encoding (i.e. '?'s) and it *seems* like changing default-charset solves the problem then what you *really* have to do is to **find the code where the default-charset is used for encoding and pass a custom charset to be used instead**.

(Like @AndreiVolgin commented: You should never rely on the system default-charset.)

### More detailed Answer

A charset specifies how chars are represented as numbers (i.e. bytes).
The internal charset of all Strings in Java is in fact UTF-16 so **the only time custom charsets become important is when converting a String to a byte-Array (`String.getBytes()`) or vice versa (`new String(byte[]`)**.

This is where the default-charset is used  if you don't pass a charset like `String.getBytes(Charset)` or `new String(byte[], Charset)`.

You get to see '?'s when different charsets are used for encoding (`String.getBytes()`) and decoding (`new String(byte[]`).

So to get rid of the '?'s **replace `String.getBytes()` by `String.getBytes(Charset)`** (or maybe replace `new String(byte[])` by `new String(byte[], Charset)` but don't know if thats a thing).

---

For me the encoding problem occured when sending some text via the internet because the String needs to be converted to `byte[]` to send it using `HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream().write(byte[])`.

To be precise: In class `com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender`, method `post(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`, line 471 was `byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();`.

I changed it (overwrote it) to `byte[] bytes = body.getBytes("UTF-8");` - solved it for me.